# WCF authentication using certificate which don't have public key

Tags: wcf, certificate

I am hosting a secured WCF service which is a **wrapper** over an existing ASMX service.

My service needs have  certificate authentication (transport level security, same as in the original service). My problem is that the users will be using **client certificates issued by original service** And not my *new* certificates.

To my knowledge you can not customize certificate authentication over Transport level security. But there must be some way to use third party cert authentication/encryption here

Does anyone having idea on how to make it possible in this case?

Answer (score 2):

How can you have a digital certificate without a public key? Digital certificates rely on asymmetric cryptography. If you don't have the public key **file**, then you can export it from the certificates you do have - but they most certainly **do** have public keys.

Comment: I understand your point.'No public key' is something told/suggested by the ppl associated with orig service.
My objective is to authenticate my users by certificates which were not issued by me. I can achieve it if it is message level security, but not sure how to make it in transport level.

Comment: So what exactly do you have and don't you have? What sort of "certificates" are these?

Comment: I don't have in depth knowledge on certificates. The difference i see in those certificates from mine are added fields
1. basic Constraint
2. CRL Distribution Point
3. Key Usage
4. Subject Key Identifier
5. Authority Key Identifier
6. Netscape cert type = SSL client auth
i am not sure if that is helpful